# modelar distribucion geometrica

Tags: r

Que comando en R studio debo utilizar para el siguiente caso?

En el lanzamiento de un dado, contar las veces que se tira el dado hasta que sale 6.

Necesito modelar una distribucion geometrica para `10000` lanzamientos asignando diferentes probabilidades y observando el comportamiento de la grafica. No se que expresion de programacion usar para contar el numero de tiradas hasta el exito (numero 6).
Gracias

Comment: si estoy de acuerdo muchas gracias ok se hace con sample, sin embargo la cuestion es otra... me interesa saber CUANTOS lanzamientos debo hacer hasta obtener un 6. Eso repetirlo 10000 veces, y luego quiero hacer una tabla de frecuencias para graficarlas, eso seria una distribucion geometrica, me interesa el numero de ensayos hasta el exito. Pero no se que comando me cuenta en cada muestra el numero de tiros (lanzamientos que no salieron seis) hasta que sale el seis. No se si me explico mejor. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

la probabilidad de obtener un 6 en una lanzada es 1/6

la probabilidad de No obtener un 6 en una lanzada es 5/6

pero tu pregunta esta enfocada con la simulacion de 1000 lanzamientos, para ellos se hace uso de `sample`.

```
probabilidades <- sample(6,1000, replace='TRUE')
probabilidadesConNo6 <- probabilidades[probabilidades < 6]

length(probabilidadesConNo6) / length(probabilidades) //esta es la probabilidad de 1000 lanzamientos
```

El replace='TRUE' para que sean independientes

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que buscas es hacer una simulación, puedes implementar en primer lugar una función que simule el arrojar los dados hasta obtener el resultado esperado:

```
intentos <- function(resultado_buscado) {
    i <- 1
    while (!(sample(1:6,size=1)==resultado_buscado)) {
        i <- i + 1
    }
    return (i)
}
```

La anterior función generará un resultado al azar entre los 6 posibles y repetirá el ciclo hasta obtener el valor que buscamos.

Luego podremos repetir el procedimiento las `n`veces que deseemos, para esto podemos usar un loop implícito con `sapply()`, por último con `table()`generaremos la tabla de frecuencias

```
table(sapply(1:10000, function(x) {intentos(6)}))

  1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15 
1665 1417 1127 1019  833  654  567  437  376  323  254  228  192  161  125 
  16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30 
 123   81   61   61   54   36   32   27   28   20   20   13   14   10    6 
  31   33   34   35   36   37   38   41   42   44   46   47   52   61 
   9    6    1    3    4    2    2    1    3    1    1    1    1    1
```